# What is the requires/provides design pattern used by the T4 RequiresProvidesDirectiveProcessor class?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, design-patterns, code-generation, t4

The MSDN Library documentation for the RequiresProvidesDirectiveProcessor class in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating namespace refers to a design pattern called "requires/provides". What is this design pattern?

> "*The abstract base class for a directive processor that defines and
>   implements a design pattern called
>   requires/provides.*" - [from MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.requiresprovidesdirectiveprocessor.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom directive implementing this pattern looks like this:

```
<#@ Custom processor="CustomDirectiveProcessor" 
    requires="name=value;name=value" 
    provides="name=value;name=value"  #>
```

It allows you to package multiple parameters instide of two standard - requires and provides. This pattern is used in directive processors generated by DSL toolkit.

Personally, I haven't found it to be particularly useful. When building a custom directive processor, I think it is clearer to separate each parameter. The amount of effort it takes is the same.